# Does blocking one channel on YouTube cause blocking other channels or account?

Tags: youtube

If I have multiple YouTube channels per single Google account and Google decides to block one of my channels, what about other channels? What about my Google account?

Comment: There really isn't any way for us to answer this. For one thing, we can't read Google's mind. If what you've done to get a channel blocked is so egregiously bad that they want to block your entire account, that's their prerogative. Any information we might offer here would just echo what they say in their Terms of Service, which you can read as well as we can.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Youtube doesn't block a single channel, it could block a single video and after the third strike could terminate the Youtube account. From [Account terminations - Youtube Help](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2802168?hl=en&ref_topic=2803138)

> Users whose accounts have been terminated are prohibited from
>   accessing, possessing or creating any other YouTube accounts. When an
>   account is terminated, the account owner will receive an email
>   detailing the reason for the suspension.

Since Gmail is the default email service for Youtube accounts, I think that the Google Account will not be blocked, just the access to Youtube with that and any other account for that user..

---

To learn about Youtube community guidelines strikes see [Community guidelines strikes - Youtube Help](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2802032?hl=en&ref_topic=2803138)